# How do I center a UIImage inside a UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to center all the UIImage images in my UITableView cell, but cannot achieve the results.

I tried searching for suggestions/solutions and found several, but nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [ [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[sponsorsLogoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath;
}
```

Added the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ....
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[sponsorsLogoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    UIImageView *pic = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:pic];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);

    ....
}
```

And also tried:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ....
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    UIImageView *pic = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    pic.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:pic];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);

    ....
}
```

And also:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ....
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    UIImageView *pic = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width / 2 , 60);
    pic.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:pic];

    ....
}
```

all 3 times received error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   _isDecompressing]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10036ada0'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you try so many changes that have nothing to do with the error? Focus on the error. Most likely your `array` contains `NSString` objects and not `UIImage` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass UITableViewCell and reposition the frame of the built in imageView in layoutSubviews to achieve what you want to do. You should never add subviews in cellForRowAtIndexPath: to the cell, it breaks MVC.

```
static NSString * const CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier"

@implementation
....

// Add this in viewDidLoad

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ....

    [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Try this instead:

```
// In a separate subclass of UITableViewCell

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,self.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);
}


// In your controller

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[sponsorsLogoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: added the suggestions in a subclass of UITableViewCell, but it seems to do nothing :(

Comment: Did you make sure to register the subclass with the table view? I also forgot to change the cell type cellForRowAtIndexPath: in my example, I will fix it now

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, as I'm still learning objective-c, but what do u mean by registering the subclass with the table view?

Comment: No problem at all, I will add that to my answer. Registering a cell with a tableView/collection view will allow the table view to take care of creating all cells, so you do not have to check if a cell is nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can just assume that dequeReusableCell will ALWAYS return a cell.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I have 2 questions though. 1: by "CustomCell" type, you mean the subclass of UITableViewCell?...2:putting the code in viewDidLoad shows "CellIdentifier" error. Shouldn't that be placed in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: You must register a cell before the tableView trys to create it. The reason your getting a "CellIdentifier" error is because you are not defining it until cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Although the template plops the declaration for CellIdentifier there its not a good spot for it. You should declare all cell identifiers as static strings at the top of your implementation file (outside of @implementation)....Yes by "CustomClass" I mean subclass UITableViewCell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65326/discussion-between-pangu-and-dboyer).

Comment: thanks for your help Boyer, I have figured it out using your suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just call cell.imageView.center?

```
NSString *image = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"img" ofType:@".png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:image];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake (cell.center.y, cell.center.x, cell.frame.size.width,     cell.frame.size.height);
cell.backgroundView = imgView;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I believed it worked, but it just stretched the image from left to right side of the screen, I tried dividing the GRect coordinates by 2, but nothing changes

Comment: This is a very awkward way of doing this. A subclass is much more clean.

Comment: @Pangu Do you mean the resizing of the image is off using UIImage?;

Comment: @DBoyer a subclass isn't a bad idea either I was just trying to keep it short and concise. It could also be done adding a property and adding a method although tableView tend to fill up fast like that. Although, you could leave the property in the tableView API and just add a category too. Just a matter of coding preference I guess.

Comment: @Cspell: 2 issues actually, yes the images are stretched across each cell, and also when I select a particular cell, the whole gray selection blocks the cell instead of being transparent

Comment: @pangu cell.selectionStyle = NO; //i'm pretty sure let me know if that doesn't work;

Comment: @pangu resizing images can be a little tricky do you know what size image you're starting with?

Comment: by setting selectionStyle to NO, the cells are un-clickable, and the image size is 600x300

Comment: that's weird use this instead though =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; @600 x 300 I definitely can't tell you how to resize without really bad distortion only thing I can tell you on that is maybe find some that are a little more proportionate to begin with. like 600 x 600 or better i.e.:landscaped images sorry..

Comment: The selection style is a backgroundView constant that determines the color of a cell when it is selected. The default value is UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue. See UITableViewCellSelectionStyle for a description of valid constants. -APPLE REFERENCE                  Copyright © 2014 Apple Inc. All rights reserved. Terms of Use | Privacy Policy | Updated: 2013-09-18

Comment: Did you intentionally flip `x` and `y` in `CGRectMake`?

Answer (score 0):

@pangu 
What about if you just did something like this to help with the image streching:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 200;
}
```

Comment: @pangu that would probably get you a little closer to what you're looking for anyway right?

Comment: Don't post a second answer. Add these details to your other answer.

Comment: oh sorry I just started using this site, I'm still learning the in's and outs I guess